# How do you remove a point from matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Lets say you have a plot in matplotlib, something like that:

```
figure = Figure()
figureCanvas = FigureCanvas(figure)
axes = figure.add_subplot(111)
axes.plot([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1], linestyle = "None", marker = "o", color = '#1f77b4', markersize = 3)
```

This would give you a plot with 3 points. How do I remove a specific point from plot, without redrawing the whole thing again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to redraw at least the plot (the `Line2D` object), otherwise there will be no change in the plot.

Without knowing the purpose of not redrawing, it's hard to judge on an acceptable solution. However, usually you would just redraw the whole canvas. 
To set new data, the `Line2D.set_data()` method can be used as shown in the following. You may press the number key (0,1,2) of the point to remove in the plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [2, 3, 1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(x, y, ls="None", marker="o", color='#1f77b4', ms=10)

def remove_point(event):
    try:
        key = int(event.key)
        xvals = x[:]
        xvals.pop(key)
        yvals = y[:]
        yvals.pop(key)
        line.set_data(xvals,yvals)
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    except:
        pass

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', remove_point)
ax.set_title("Press number of point to remove")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your solution worked for me and I'm fine with that, but it still feels a little odd to just replace all the data with set_data function. Is there good way to not replace data in line, but update it? Maybe you can remove point by index, like line.remove(index)

Comment: What exactly is the difference between "replacing" and "updating"? Internally a new numpy array needs to be created in both cases, so there is no gain in doing it differently.